# Referenced .Net assembly not found at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

Here's the scenario.
I created a brand new Asp.Net DNX RC2 Final project. I also added a .Net class library project to my solution (both under FX 4.6.1). The class library project is located in the src folder.

Then, I add a reference to the class library, and it can successfully restore all packages after making changes to the project.json file.

I've added a simple foo function to my class library

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static string Foo()
        {
            return "Bar";
        }
    }
}
```

and finally in my Home/Index view, I have added the following on top

```
<div>
    @(ClassLibrary1.Class1.Foo())
</div>
```

The solution compiles with no errors.
You may think so far so good, let's continue.

Then, when I run the solution, the following is shows:

[image]

At runtime, my class library is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar situation.  In my case I got a RazorEngine exception in Visual Studio which at least gave me an indication of what was going on (it was something like a missing reference exception, even though the class library was added as a reference).

The only way that I could get it working (I'm hoping there is a better way), was to add the following code to my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    var previous = options.CompilationCallback;
    options.CompilationCallback = (context) =>
    {
        previous?.Invoke(context);
        context.Compilation = context.Compilation.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ClassLibrary1.Class1).Assembly.Location));
    };
});
```

I got the idea from the following websites:

[Callback on RazorViewEngineOptions](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4087#issuecomment-191899644)

[Configure RazorViewEngine](http://www.hossambarakat.net/2016/02/16/asp-net-core-mvc-feature-folders/)

I did confirm that your example is working when I add the code mentioned above.